# Migrate process plugin entity_lookup: value_key: field with multiple values

Tags: migrations, 10

The field "field_erp_code" has multiple values, but it seems that migrate only looks at delta 0 of that field. Can this be done by with the entity_lookup plugin?

```
 field_product_category:
    plugin: entity_lookup
    source: Product category
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    bundle_key: vid
    bundle: product_category
    value_key: field_erp_code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entity_lookup` plugin from the `migrate_plus` module already supports multi-valued fields. But you can specify manually the `operator: IN` if necessary.

See [\Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityLookup](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityLookup.php#L240).

Try to debug this plugin and see what comes as the value.